# django: how to filter model field values with out space?

Tags: python, regex, django

I have asked this question before. May be due to lack of desired answers, again, I take this as a opportunity to explain my problem in a nice fashion in this space.

Please note: **I am using MySQL database**

I have a model called **City**. It contains **id, name**.

```
id      name
1       New York
2       New India
3       New USA
4       New UK
```

Now by using the below syntax

**Please note:** As a sample example I put static value i.e. **New** in the below syntax. At the end it should be dynamic value.

City.objects.filter(name__icontains="New")

Obviously I get **New York, New India, New USA,New UK**

From this point I am good.

---

Now moving to the my problem.I want to filter only **New York** city name. The user could type **newyork (or) New York (or) NEWYORK (or) NEw yOrk (or) some other way**, but at the end I have to strip the spaces from the model field value and get desired results.

```
City.objects.filter(name__iregex= "newyork")  ?// How to fix this one

CURRENT OUTPUT is:
[]

DESIRED OUTPUT is:
New York
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL is the database i am using

Comment: City.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains='New York') | Q(name__icontains='NewYork'))

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [custom lookup function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-lookups/) for this.

```
from django.db.models import Transform

class SpaceRemovedValue(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'nospaces'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        return "REPLACE(%s, ' ', '')" % lhs, params

from django.db.models import CharField
CharField.register_lookup(SpaceRemovedValue)
```

Now you can use it:

```
City.objects.filter(name__nospaces= "newyork")
```

**Note** this is pretty inefficient. It requires MySQL to scan and process every row in the City table; if you have more than a few, it will take a while.

An alternative approach would be to save a spaces-removed version of the name field into a separate field, which you could then query directly. You could override the `save` method to automatically populate the field before saving it.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to add an optional whitespace character `\s*` in between each one of the search string characters:

```
def insert_whitespace(string):
    s = []
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        s.append(string[i:i+1])
    return '\\s*'.join(s)
```

Then

```
City.objects.filter(name__iregex= insert_whitespace("newyork"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the best solution, but it may help.

```
# Query you entire table
from myapp.models import City

cities = City.objects.all().values('name', 'id')  # If it get extra values later
user_entry = 'newyork'

def is_match(cities, user_entry):
    result_list = []
    for city in cities:
        for value in city['name'].lower().split(' '):
            if value in user_entry.lower():
                l.append(city['id'])
                break
    return result_list

# Then call
is_match(cities=cities, user_entry=user_entry)

# Should return something like this
[1L]  # A list with id of possibles matchs
```

The function `is_match` could be a list comprehension but in this way is more legible I think.

This will be more inefficient with bigger data, but may could give you an idea to start.